# Azure Logic Apps Designer expands all the the top level actions every time I enter edit mode

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm using Logic Apps with the old Designer (Not the preview designer) and every time I enter edit mode on any of our logic apps, every single top level action block is opened up, making it load slower while also being more time consuming to get a high level view of what the logic app flow is without scrolling around.

I compared my Portal settings with my teammates and everything checks out. My teammates are not facing this issue on the same Azure resources. Does anyone else face this issue while working with Logic Apps?

Any possible solutions to open up the Designer without getting the expanded actions would be much appreciated!

---

Answer (score 0):

After trying from my end i am able to get this done by following below approach.

- Initially i cleared all cache then as shown in below image disabled logic App workflow and then enable it and then click on Edit

[image]

- Then by clicking on edit button i am able to see my workflow as shown below.
  [image]
- If still you are facing the same issue as shown in image using the code view editor instead of the designer is one workaround. The activities in the code view editor can be manually collapsed because they are not expanded by default. When the user reopens the workflow in the code view editor, the collapsed state of the activities will be retained.
  [image]
- According this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-diagnosing-failures?tabs=consumption#usually-my-workflow-completes-within-10-seconds-but-sometimes-completion-can-take-much-longer-how-can-i-make-sure-the-workflow-always-finishes-within-10-seconds) the workloads of other customers may have a detrimental impact on the performance of your workflow because consumption workflows are executed on multi-tenant Azure Logic Apps. So, i am just suggesting in future you go with Create Standard processes, which operate in single-tenant Azure Logic Apps, for more dependable performance. More control over scaling up or down for performance improvement.
- The other ways you may go with are visual studio or .json edit mode. If you still facing the issue raise MS support to disable auto-expansion of actions in the designer.

Reference MS document [1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/a-new-foundation-for-logic-apps-designer/ba-p/3662025) and document [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-azure-portal?tabs=standard).